# How to develop an application for Android which uses Google Calendar API

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-api, google-calendar-api

I just started doing some Android app development, and I decided I'm going to write an app to work with [Google Calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Calendar).

The first problem that came to me is that I can't add any Gmail account on the emulator. When I go to *settings* -> *accounts*, I can only add an Exchange account.

This raises a question how should I develop such application. I know that I should mock the API while I'm running tests, but how am I supposed to run the app on the emulator?

Should I just test it on mocked API with [JUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JUnit) and then run it on *production* phone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for the emulator set up for a Google account, well, it depends on the Android version you have in your [AVD](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html): for example for 2.2, go to Settings/Accounts & Sync, click on Add account and Google, etc.

As for the Google Calendar access, the best way is to use the [Google Calendar API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/).

Please note: there is not yet an official Android SDK API for the Calendar access.

Comment: If it is possible, re-start your emulator with option "Wipe user data" on, or create brand new AVD.

Comment: I realized that I created AVD without Google API ... it works now with new one with the API enabled.

Answer (score 3):

There is a good example of accessing Google Calendar Data API from Android using the [Google API Client Library for Java](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) at [calendar-v2-atom-android-sample](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-v2-atom-android-sample/instructions.html?r=default).  There are detailed instructions there for setting up the proper package:

- Window > Android SDK and AVD Manager

  - Follow instructions to install Package "Google API's by Google Inc., Android API 8"
  - Follow instructions to create a new Android Virtual Device based on target "Google API's (Google Inc.) - API Level 8"
  - Click "Start..." (wait a while...)
  - On home screen in emulator, click Menu button, Settings
  - Click on "Accounts and Sync"
  - Click on "Add Account"
  - Click "Google" and follow instructions

Disclaimer: I am an owner of the [Google API Client Library for Java](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) project.

Comment: I downloaded sample project and did all the steps mentioned in Instructions. When I run the application, I am getting force close.. Prints this in log: 
"04-27 13:36:52.934: E/AndroidRuntime(2951): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil"


Can you please help me out?